# Exclude some authors from query

Tags: wp-query, query, author

This script list users with their last post. How to exclude some authors from guery ?

```
<?php

    //List of users sorted descending by date of lastest post written by user
    $uc=array();
    $blogusers = get_users_of_blog();

    if ($blogusers) 
    {
        foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) 
        {
            $user = new WP_User( $bloguser->user_id );
            if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) )
            {
                $userpost = get_posts('showposts=1&author='.$bloguser->user_id);
                $uc[$bloguser->user_id] = '';
                if ($userpost) 
                {
                    $uc[$bloguser->user_id]=$userpost[0]->post_date;
                }
            }
        }
        arsort($uc);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($uc as $key => $value) 
        {
            $user = get_userdata($key);
            $post_count = count_user_posts($user->ID);
            if ($post_count && $i < 10) 
            {
                $author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url($key);

                //preparing query for titles
                $args=array(
                'author' => $user->ID ,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
                );
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) 
                {
                    //echo 'List of Posts for ' . user->user_firstname . ' ' . $user->user_lastname;
                    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To exclude authors you add a minus sign in front of the user id. So in your case it could look like this:

```
$args=array(
    'author' => '-2, -3, -4', //excludes users with id 2, 3 and 4.
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
);
```

Read more in [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters)

Comment: Thank you for answer,but It is not work.

Comment: Hmm yeah, that's right. Including AND excluding in the same query doesn't really make sense. Remove $user->ID from the author and use only exclude. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you again. But it is does not work too )

Comment: Alright, try changing it to an array of the authors you want to exclude. I'll edit again.

Comment: there is an error - 
Warning: urldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/z/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 2275

Comment: Ok, now I've finally tried it for myself and it does indeed work for me when using a string and minus signs before the id's I want to exclude (edited answer to reflect that). Try that again, and if it doesn't work, please specify what isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Hey use this to grab all users excluding users with ID - 1,2,4

```
$blogusers = get_users(array('exclude' => array(1,2,4)));
```

> #### Note -
>
> The function [`get_users_of_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users_of_blog) is depricated, so it'd be good idea to use [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function which supports **excludeing** of users by their IDs.

Comment: you're using `get_users_of_blog` to get the list of users, then you should exclude some users right in that function. that's idea.